# Typescript—Comparing KnockoutObservable<number> with number

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm trying to do what should be a simple operation, but I'm running into a peculiar issue. I need to disable a button unless a certain value is above 0. Basically, my code is like this:

```
currentIndex: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>();
canActivate: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;

this.canActivate = ko.computed<boolean>(function ()) {
    if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
});
```

In this form, it always returns false. If I replace > with !=, it always returns true. I have a function to display currentIndex and as I click around on different items, it changes just how I'd expect. However, I just can't compare it to a number. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this.currentIndex)` or `console.log(typeof this.currentIndex)?`?  Also (and I'm unfamiliar with Typescript), I'd think that `this.currentIndex` might be a massive Knockout function.  Is this the correct way to get its value? (i.e. `this.currentIndex()` in vanilla Knockout)?

Comment: I haven't tried console.log, but I have a similar function to display it in my UI. Every time I select an item, the index number changes exactly how I'd expect it to. Also, using this.currentIndex() returns an the error "Undefined is not a function."

Comment: You should log the value of `this.currentIndex` in the console when `canActivate()` fires, before the return statement is evaluated, so that you can see what `this.currentIndex` is.  I think you're trying to define it as a Knockout observable, which is a function and not a value.  If it's not a Knockout observable, then using `this.currentIndex() > 0` will fail.  Also, `this.currentIndex > 0` should auto-fail, like Wayne is saying in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the posters above said, you need to both create `canActivate` using the fat arrow and evaluate the observable. Something like this:

```
this.canActivate = ko.computed<boolean>(() => {
    return this.currentIndex() > 0;
});
```

Typescript uses the fat arrow syntax in order to capture the `this` context. If you create it using `function ()` the context will not be the context you expect, which is why you get the undefined function error.

Answer (score 1):

In Knockout you need to evaluate the observable to get it's value, that's because observables are functions. In this case to get the value of currentIndex you would:

instead of:

```
this.currentIndex
```

you would do:

```
this.currentIndex()
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

class Example {
    currentIndex: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>();
    canActivate: KnockoutComputed<boolean> = ko.computed<boolean>(() => {
        if (this.currentIndex() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Any idea why I would get the "undefined is not a function" error?

Comment: Can you click on it and post the line that that occurred?

Comment: I think you should be also use this.canActivate = ko.computed(() => { });